# ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:747) on OS X

Tags: macos, pandas, macos-sierra, pyopenssl, python-3.6

I am trying this bit of code.

```
import pandas as pd

fiddy_states=pd.read_html('https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states')

print(fiddy_states[0])
```

I am getting following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1318, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 964, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1400, in connect
    server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 401, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 808, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1061, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 683, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:747)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/avinashmore/Desktop/Desktop pe Desktop/Programming/Python/Pandas/panda4BuidlingDataset.py", line 10, in <module>
    fiddy_states= pd.read_html('https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/html.py", line 896, in read_html
    keep_default_na=keep_default_na)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/html.py", line 733, in _parse
    raise_with_traceback(retained)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py", line 339, in raise_with_traceback
    raise exc.with_traceback(traceback)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:747)>
```

I have tried following things:
Uninstall and install certifi
and all the other steps mentioned in related answers on stack overflow.
Still unable to fix it.

Please help.

Comment: Sometimes I hate the internet. People all over are getting this error and are unable to fix it because nobody else cares.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, and after some searching, i came across this
https://bugs.python.org/issue28150

There is a command-line-runnable script ("/Applications/Python 3.6/Install Certificates.command") that uses pip to install certifi and creates a symlink in the OpenSSL directory to certifi's installed bundle location.

This worked for me, maybe you can take a look.