# SSLError using Requests and Python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, openssl, python-requests

I'm getting an `SSLError` while submitting a request against `https://myaccount.xcelenergy.com` (and am not nearly enough of an SSL expert to understand why). Can you help me see what the issue is (and how to address it)?

**Environment**

- macOS 10.13.2
- LibreSSL 2.2.7 (installed via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/))
- Python 3.6.4 (installed via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/))
- Requests 2.18.4 (installed via [pipenv](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv))
- Certifi 2017.11.5 (installed via [pipenv](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv))

**Code**

```
import requests

requests.get('https://myaccount.xcelenergy.com')
```

**Stacktrace**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/abach/.local/share/virtualenvs/pyxcel-PG9DCiyE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 595, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "/Users/abach/.local/share/virtualenvs/pyxcel-PG9DCiyE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 816, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "/Users/abach/.local/share/virtualenvs/pyxcel-PG9DCiyE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 326, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "/Users/abach/.local/share/virtualenvs/pyxcel-PG9DCiyE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 329, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 407, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 814, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1068, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 689, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:777)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/abach/.local/share/virtualenvs/pyxcel-PG9DCiyE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 440, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/Users/abach/.local/share/virtualenvs/pyxcel-PG9DCiyE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 639, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/Users/abach/.local/share/virtualenvs/pyxcel-PG9DCiyE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 388, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='myaccount.xcelenergy.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:777)'),))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/abach/.local/share/virtualenvs/pyxcel-PG9DCiyE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/abach/.local/share/virtualenvs/pyxcel-PG9DCiyE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/abach/.local/share/virtualenvs/pyxcel-PG9DCiyE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Users/abach/.local/share/virtualenvs/pyxcel-PG9DCiyE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/abach/.local/share/virtualenvs/pyxcel-PG9DCiyE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 506, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='myaccount.xcelenergy.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:777)'),))
```

**What I've Tried (to no avail)**

```
# Specifically calling out local cert chain:
requests.get('https://myaccount.xcelenergy.com', verify='/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem')

# Using Certifi's old chain:
requests.get('https://myaccount.xcelenergy.com', verify=certifi.old_where())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently a known issue with [OSX's Python3.6 and OpenSSL](https://bugs.python.org/issue28150) that might be related to what you're seeing. I was able to fix it by installing certifi, then making a symlink in OpenSSL's directory. All of that can be done for you by running the following from bash:

`Applications/Python 3.6/Install Certificates.command`

See this related question: [ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:747) on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40038246/ssl-sslerror-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certificate-verify-failed-ssl-c#41621063)

Comment: That did it. Thank you!